# Connecting a Lithium battery directly to the GSM module

Tags: embedded, wireless, battery-operated, gsm, gprs

I have a GSM module (M66 from Quectel) and a single cell Lithium battery,Based on Datasheet module operated in the 3.3 ~ 4.6 V and as I know battery deliver 3.7 ~ 4.2 V based on it's sate of charge.Then is this possible to fed the module directly from battery, without using any other chip (like MIC29302 which was recommended by Quectel)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need over-discharge protection, to prevent damage to the battery under low power or fault conditions.

Typically it is safe to discharge Li-ion cells to at least 3.3V, but you should check for your specific chemistry.

But no, you should not need any kind of buck or boost converter.